# “Float” two absolutely positioned nested divs

Tags: css

I want to position two nested divs of unknown width slightly above their inner content. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdvzsxnq/

Absolute positioning

```
position: absolute;
top: -15px
```

puts the two on top of each other, while I want the second one to be just to right of the first. I could add

```
left: 150px;
```

to the second one, as I did in the fiddle, but that works only if I know the width of the first one. And in the real case I don't.

Also

```
float: left;
```

doesn't work with absolutely positions divs.

Is there a way to get, in effect, a float:left on these absolutely positioned divs?

(If this could be responsive, all the better. There might be several such notes, not just two, and they might not fit in a narrow window.)

---

Edit: Best I have so far is to assume a maximum number of such notes and set the width of each to a fraction (say 1/3), then set left:33% on the second, 66% on the third. Not ideal but it’s simple.

```
div > .overlay + div > .overlay { left: 33% }
div > .overlay + div > .overlay + div > .overlay { left: 66% }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ak3mpe2n/4/

Still looking for the ideal . . .

Comment: are those 2divs always there ? are those 2 div always made of a single line ? What is the purpose of those divs ? A padding top could be usefull, coordonates left and right too .

Comment: Please describe your functional requirements of this part, what does it have to do?

Comment: In a nest of DIVs, each DIV has some note before its main content—#outerNote and #innerNote in the fiddle. Based on some user action,  Javascript will turn that note on or off. When on, the note will overlay the main text, anchored to it. In a nest, the anchors are the same, the upper left corner of the inner content. So the notes will overlap. Only the top will be readable. Requirement: move the notes around so all can be read.

Answer (score 1):

Float actually works, if you just wrap both in an absolutely positioned div:

```css
[relative] {
  position: relative;
}
[absolute] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
[float] { 
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1rem; 
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
[float][right] { 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div relative>
  <div absolute>
    <div float>First float</div>
    <div float>Second float</div>
    <div float right>I float, right?</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>[32] But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
```

Comment: Yes, but the divs I'm trying to "float" are nested.

Comment: Web design is all about displaying information according to visual specs. Markup doesn't matter, programming language doesn't matter. All that matters is the display of the required information according to the required specifications. What are the specs here, @JPM? What is the requirement? Before you tell me markup must stay the same, I'll tell you it won't work if it stays the same. You'll need to create an absolute parent on the fly and snatch all floated children in it, using `javascript` to be able to display this data in this manner.

Comment: But, if it comes down to `JavaScript`, you could just calculate the absolute elements' position on the fly, like pinterest does with their pins. There's no need to move them around in DOM. Bottom line is: using only CSS, what you want is not possible. What you position absolute can no longer influence whatever is in the normal flow. The only way to relate two or more absolutely positioned elements (using CSS) is to remove their `position:absolute` and place them in the same absolutely positioned parent.

Comment: I'm now thinking of just forcing each note to have a width of 25%. Then use CSS to set left:25% for the second, 50% for the third, 75% for the fourth (assuming there won't be more than four).

Comment: @JPM, I now understand your question better (I admit I only read it in diagonal initially - and I apologize - just trying to spend less time on questions, when possible). Here's how I'd do it: if you only need to display the note once, build a container for the notes and on whatever action makes the note visible you push the note to that container, from where it is (hidden, inline). If you need to toggle them on/off, you clone them and keep a reference. When toggled, if they exist in the "display board", you just remove the clone. If not, you add one. Need an example?

Comment: The notes appear while the mouse is over a SHOW NOTES icon. I'm showing/hiding with jQuery .show/.hide. Simple. Your thought is to create some new DIV in the DOM, the “display board”? Then toggle that board? (The document could have dozens of these.) I guess so. It would work. I was just hoping for some little CSS magic to save a bunch of work/debugging/etc. Maybe just crudely assigning each a fraction of the width would be enough.

Comment: (By the way @Andrei, is that trickery using custom attributes instead of classes common and well regarded?)

Comment: If you need to show all notes in a container and not a just a few, based on whatever conditions, you should just build the billboard on page load, pick all notes, place them and display when the button is pressed/hovered. Regarding the attribute trick, the spec says they should have a hyphen, just like custom elements. But that's just so there's no risk of collision with native attributes. However, it works in all major browsers. An answer on SO? - Cool. Doing it in anything that's gonna be used by millions? - I wouldn't.

Comment: Uptick for the insights. (Uptick the Q?) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will satisfy, as I have rearranged some markup, but its maybe worth considering as an approach:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outer {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outerNote {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
}

#innerNote {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
The cause of America is in a great measure the cause of all mankind. Many circumstances have, and will arise, which are not local, but universal, and through which the principles of all lovers of mankind are affected, and in the event of which, their
affections are interested.

<div id="outer">

  <div id="outerNote">
    Note for the outer div.
  </div>

  <div id="innerNote">
    And then a note for the inner div.
  </div>

</div>

Ipsum lorem and some more ipsum lorem. Ipsum lorem and some more ipsum lorem. Ipsum lorem and some more ipsum lorem. Ipsum lorem and some more ipsum lorem. Ipsum lorem and some more ipsum lorem. Ipsum lorem and some more ipsum lorem. Ipsum lorem and somemoreipsum
```

Comment: Yes, float works if the floated items are siblings in the markup. But here they aren't.